# How do I automatically submit an Android app for review using FASTLANE?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console, fastlane, fastlane-supply

I'm setting up my production line at Fastlane.
The code below shows the process carried out to search for the latest version in Internal Tests that is on Google Play Console and then send it to production.

The problem is that I'm not able to automatically send this production version to Google for analysis, I'm having to do this manually by accessing the Google Play Console.

Would anyone know how I can do this automatically through FASTLANE?

```
desc "Promote the current beta build to the production track"
lane :production do
  version_codes = google_play_track_version_codes(track: "internal")
  version_code = version_codes.first

  supply_params = {
    track: "internal",
    track_promote_to: "production",
    version_code: version_code
  }
  supply(supply_params)
end
```

**I'm trying this for Android**

This is my log

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here is the status of APP on Google Play Console

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update your FASTLANE, it's a possibility!

Comment: Does not work! Fastlane has been updated

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).